# Typescript different generic in array of interface

Tags: reactjs, typescript, typescript-generics

I've a type with a generic to define some extra options for a function component.

`type FCWithOptions<T> = React.FC<{options?: T}>;`

Using this type I'm defining some components with their own extra properties

```
interface ComponentAOptions {
    option1: string;
    option2: number;
}

interface ComponentBOptions {
    prop1: boolean;
    prop2: Record<string, string>;
}

type ComponentAFC = FCWithOptions<ComponentAOptions>
type ComponentBFC = FCWithOptions<ComponentBOptions>

const ComponentA: ComponentAFC = ({options}) => {
    return <>Component A</>
}

const ComponentB: ComponentBFC = ({options}) => {
    return <>Component B</>
}
```

then what I need is to pass these components in a container component using an array of interfaces that contains the component to pass and the custom options of that component through a property.

```
interface ComponentValue<T>{
    component: FCWithOptions<T>;
    componentOptions?: T;
}
interface MainComponentProps<C>{
    components: ComponentValue<C>[]
}
function MainComponent<C>({}: MainComponentProps<C>) {
    return <>Main</>
}
```

What I should be able to do is something like this:

```
<MainComponent components={[
    {component: ComponentA, componentOptions: {option1: "", option2: 2}},
    {component: ComponentB, componentOptions: { prop1: true, props: {} }}
]} />
```

But it works only for the first element of the array, if I add other elements I get some typescript assertions

How could I achieve this?
Thanks

[Here a playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgIilQ3wFgAoC4AOxiSk3STgGFdJqlaBBAeTBjAI1AM5wA3hTjS4EAUOoBGAFxwRMKDQDmAbiky5g4QCZV1AK4gARvT3kAvhSq16jNMzbhhXGACF%20RqIS%20tJgOGAqcFYQEAA2qNR2MnBhcqaISGjQACYAPOqa1FoANGoa2gB8do6U5DAAnmDMAGIsAOrAMAAWAQoiuQAqFXAAvBnoMAB0rbnihn0A-KoD9lVOdY0e7N48raNwrR3dvcL9nhw%20fPKnFRQNTazbnLS%20e2OHnT3XornnO34nUS3WpZUTwP7PGDcVQQy5vOAACjm3xE9gAlKNhpJyMkiDBzFBqHBchVYbQ4NxcgB6YE1Cig9SPLyQ3wwp4%20V4sfZI%20andGY4I4mR4glEklk%20C%20am09Y0OgMJhMi60ABqKFi5iQgwq2OSWWZPlUH2OKO1SRk%20uVMEBIiWcAG1VlLgV7jgAFkUDQJQAFcJnHUhOCW-4iNkG1XqzW-CoAbQAuhQ6eRMOZqBgFO7PdQJdGkfZVB6vezaL65P6MbrhUh8YTiRVC9RpYn1rkGxKg8WYCIRuIY4HxMHIWGrdxSoOfDbVMjApF8PhSrzqOljPZ7MV%20%20PaMP-r4x53JxIUuFIhpNaVUmBQxJ7HBV%20s4zeaUA)

Comment: Does this question depend on react? If so you might want to tag it as such. If not you might want to [edit] the code to be a [mre] without dependence on third-party libraries.

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/Navl9m) meet your needs? (Note there seems do be a typo where you wrote `props` instead of `prop2`.) If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz Yes, it is exactly what I was looking for. I didn't knew that the spread operator could be used like that in typescript. Thanks! I've a curiosity though. Why the generated error is for the `component` property and not for the `componentOptions`?

Comment: That's a followup question about inference site priorities and out of scope here.  In short, `componentOptions` is a higher priority inference site for `T` because it's directly of type `T` and not of a more complex type function of `T`. So it infers `T` from `componentOptions` and then checks it, at which point a mismatched `component` will be seen as an error. If you need more than that then you should move it to a new question post (after searching for duplicates). I'll write up an answer to the question as asked when I get a chance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have a generic type `F<T>` and need to represent an *array* of values of that type where each element of the array has a different choice of `T`, that is, if you need a [tuple type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#tuple-types) like `[F<T0>, F<T1>, F<T2>, ⋯ , F<TN>]`, then the best approach is probably to use a [mapped tuple/array type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-1.html#mapped-types-on-tuples-and-arrays) over a tuple of just the `T0`, `T1`, etc types.  That is, if you have the type `type T = [T0, T1, T2, ⋯, TN]` and then you can apply `type MapF<T> = {[I in keyof T]: F<T[I]>}` to it to get `[F<T0>, F<T1>, F<T2>, ⋯ , F<TN>]`.

That means we should change your code to look like this:

```
interface MainComponentProps<C extends any[]> {
    components: [...{ [I in keyof C]: ComponentValue<C[I]> }]
}

function MainComponent<C extends any[]>({ }: MainComponentProps<C>) {
    return <>Main</>
}
```

(where we're using `C` in place of `T` and `ComponentValue<⋯>` in place of of `F<⋯>`.)  The only difference is that I've wrapped the type of `components` with a [variadic tuple type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-0.html#variadic-tuple-types) (`[...⋯]`) in order to hint to the compiler that we want it to infer a *tuple* and not an unordered array of arbitrary length when calling `MainComponent`.  (This use of variadic tuple types is described in [ms/TS#39094](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/39094), "The type `[...T]`, where `T` is an array-like type parameter, can conveniently be used to indicate a preference for inference of tuple types").

Let's test it out:

```
<MainComponent components={[
    { component: ComponentA, componentOptions: { option1: "", option2: 2 } },
    { component: ComponentB, componentOptions: { prop1: true, prop2: {} } }
]} />

// MainComponentProps<[{ option1: string; option2: number; }, { prop1: boolean; prop2: {}; }]>
```

Looks good.  The type `C` is inferred as `[{ option1: string; option2: number; }, { prop1: boolean; prop2: {}; }]` and therefore the mapped type `[...{ [I in keyof C]: ComponentValue<C[I]> }]` matches the type of the `components` property.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgIilQ3wFgAoC4AOxiSk3STgGFdJqlaBBAeTBjAI1AM5wA3hTjS4EAUOoBGAFxwRMKDQDmAbiky5g4QCZV1AK4gARvT3kAvhSq16jNMzbhhXGACF+RqIS+tJgOGAqcFYQEAA2qNR2MnBhcqaISGjQACYAPOqa1FoANGoa2gB8do6U5DAAnmDMAGIsAOrAMAAWAQoiuQAqFXAAvBnoMAB0rbnisvLCIgD8qgNw9lVOdY0e7N48raNwrR3dvYu5nhw+fAuiFRQNTax7nLS+h2MnnT13-Vf7Pzne5bLKieAAt4wbiqSE3T5wAAUc0MfXWAEpRsNJORkkQYOYoNQ4LkKnDaHBuLkAPQPBygxYQ14+Xyw5nvBHI+aBMT2TEjbEhOD4wnE0nk+C+Gl0mrOOgMJgvLxQgBqKFi5iQg0FuJkWWVPlU3zOf21ST17JgwOWq2qWxo8rczAAsigaBKAArhf5wJAADzo1GyYhQ1HqAG0ALo65L6660ESqcOTFNzcMASTgNDgAGskPUIJhWJG2QbaGqNVqWBno+tIxRZeRMOZqBgFHBXe7LZdfQGuMG4KGI9GufZVJ3qJ7vZcKpicXikASiSSKhPpQ2trkJxK4HHASIRuJw0K5nuoaX49DSmefNbVCi7pF8PhSqiTKpjOt1sUT7vLRfAV8a9LTvCQUnCSINE1UpUjAdJxHsL8akjRDaS2alqQ7N1J0tL05H6cMH0CSICm0HRuQUdILGsWxvzA2DImiOIEnI2D4Pscj7GjIA)